# Proplem with baking in Substance Painter

Tags: blender, substance

Made a plane model in blender and exported it to substance painter. But when i bake it in painter it gets these wierd map errors. Its mainly in the ambient occlusion and curveture maps. Does anybody have an idea what might couse this or how to fix it

[Picture of plane with the wierd "artifacts" in Painter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkvNN.png)

Comment: As additional debugging info please show the export window from blender. (I copy this from an answer which I worry might be deleted for asking this.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload the export window from blender? You should check what is wrong there, or when you create a new file in substance painter you should also check the import options.

Comment: Asking for an upload, i.e. more debugging info dilutes this answer. Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."